# Authentication code not working in android studio(SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to android studio and trying to work on simple login form which is my lab assignment.
When I click on login button it says username or password wrong even if it is true.
SqlHelper.java

```
 package com.example.mogli.henabenparekhrajthakkar_comp304_lab4;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mogli on 11/30/2017.
 */

public class SqlHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hospital.db";
    //nurse table name & columns
    private static final String NURSE_TABLE_NAME = "nurses";
    private static final String NURSE_COLUMN_ID = "nurseId";
    private static final String NURSE_COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "nurseFirstName";
    private static final String NURSE_COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "nurseLastName";
    private static final String NURSE_COLUMN_DEPARTMENT = "nurseDepartment";
    private static final String NURSE_COLUMN_PASSWORD = "nursePassword";
    //doctor table name & columns
    private static final String DOCTOR_TABLE_NAME = "doctors";
    private static final String DOCTOR_COLUMN_ID = "doctorId";
    private static final String DOCTOR_COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "doctorFirstName";
    private static final String DOCTOR_COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "doctorLastName";
    private static final String DOCTOR_COLUMN_DEPARTMENT = "doctorDepartment";
    private static final String DOCTOR_COLUMN_PASSWORD = "doctorPassword";

    private static final String NURSE_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists nurses( nurseId text primary key not null, "
    + "nurseFirstName text not null, nurseLastName text not null, nurseDepartment text not null, nursePassword text not null );";

    private static final String DOCTOR_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists doctors( doctorId text primary key not null, "
     + "doctorFirstName text not null, doctorLastName text not null, doctorDepartment text not null, doctorPassword text not null );";

    //insert query
    /*private String insertIntoNurse = "INSERT INTO nurses (nurseId, nurseFirstName, nurseLastName, nurseDepartment, nursePassword)"
    +"VALUES ('john123', 'john', 'doe', 'd1', '123john' ), ('jonahdoe', 'jonah', 'doe', 'd2', '123jonah'), ('hannah123', 'hannah', 'montana', 'd3', 'hm123');";*/

    public SqlHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(NURSE_TABLE_CREATE);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DOCTOR_TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("myMsg", "Error creating table");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        String nurse_query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NURSE_TABLE_NAME;
        String doctor_query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DOCTOR_TABLE_NAME;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(nurse_query);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(doctor_query);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                NURSE_COLUMN_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = NURSE_COLUMN_ID + " = ?" + " AND " + NURSE_COLUMN_PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

        // query user table with conditions
        /**
         * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
         * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
         * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
         */
        Cursor cursor = db.query(NURSE_TABLE_NAME, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public String searchPass(String NURSE_COLUMN_ID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "select nurseId, nursePassword from "+ NURSE_TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor =sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        String a, b;
        b = "";
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                a = cursor.getString(0);
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                if(a.equals(NURSE_COLUMN_ID))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }
    public void addNurses(Nurse nurse)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NURSE_COLUMN_ID, nurse.getNurseId());
        values.put(NURSE_COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, nurse.getNurseFirstName());
        values.put(NURSE_COLUMN_LAST_NAME, nurse.getNurseLastName());
        values.put(NURSE_COLUMN_DEPARTMENT, nurse.getNurseDepartment());
        values.put(NURSE_COLUMN_PASSWORD, nurse.getNursePassword());
        db.insert(NURSE_TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
    public List<Nurse> getAllNurses() {
        List<Nurse> nurseList = new ArrayList<Nurse>();
// Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + NURSE_TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Nurse nurse = new Nurse();
                nurse.setNurseId(cursor.getString(0));
                nurse.setNurseFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
                nurse.setNurseLastName(cursor.getString(2));
                nurse.setNurseDepartment(cursor.getString(3));
                nurse.setNursePassword(cursor.getString(4));
// Adding contact to list
                nurseList.add(nurse);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

// return contact list
        return nurseList;
    }
}
```

In the log file the database is created and data is inserted. but the login code is giving false in the log console even if the username and password is correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I appreciate your feedback. I have removed all the other files which i think are not  necessary. Keeping the sqlhandler as it is, to give better view of what I am doing.